# Place a number in worksheet B, if keyword is found in cell on worksheet A

Tags: if-statement, copy

I think there's a formula for this but not sure how to do it.
I want a cell in worksheet B to check a cell in worksheet A.
If the cell in worksheet A says "TAGGING", I want the number "1" placed in the cell in worksheet B.

(hopefully that made sense)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is this

```
=IF(SheetA!A1 = "TAGGING", 1, 0)
```

This will be done in the respective cell in SheetB

Comment: Ahh thank you, couldn't get the order right. (probably because I'm a noob.) Thanks!

Comment: :-) You might want to accept and upvote this answer then

Comment: Ah, didn't even know I could do that :D Noob to Stackoverflow too. On followup question. Now let's say I wanted to check for the word TAGGING on cells A1-A5. I tried =IF(SheetA!A1:A5 = "TAGGING", 1, 0) but that didn't work.

Comment: This requires excel-fu. . . I would add a hidden column in SheetA where I would do a formula to store 1 in case of TAGGING and 0 otherwise. Then I can safely sum on SheetB.

Comment: Hmm, think we misunderstood each other. I don't need to add up each time it says tagging, I just need it to slap a 1 there if it sees it in any of those columns. For this spreadsheet it's not going to show up more than once, but it might be in any of those columns.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(SheetA!A1:SheetA!A5,"TAGGING")>0,"YES","NO")

Comment: Ah! Actually figured it out myself. You can slap an & and put in more than one function, so I slapped a few of them together to check each cell. =IF(SheetA!A1 = "TAGGING", 1, 0)&=IF(SheetA!A2 = "TAGGING", 1, 0)&etc. Not as pretty as yours but works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Went with your way in the end just to be neater. Worked great. :)